# React, Axios, PokeAPI: undefined reading Map

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, pokeapi

To improve my React skills I was following [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=o3ZUc7zH8BE) to how create a list of name using [PokeAPI](https://pokeapi.co/).

I am stopped at 11.35, because I put this code as the tutorial show (the first block is from App.js, the second is from a component call PokemonList.js) :

```js
function App() {
  const [pokemon, setPokemon] = useState([])

  useEffect(()=>{

    axios.get("https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon").then(res=> {
      setPokemon(res.data.result.map(p => p.name))
    })
  }, [])
  
   return (
    <PokemonList pokemon={pokemon}/>
  );
}

export default App;
```

```js
export default function PokemonList({pokemon}){
    return (
        <div>
            {pokemon.map(p => (
                <div key={p}>{p}</div>
            ))}
        </div>
    )
}
```

But in the console I have the error message: *Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'map')*

I have understand that I need to put a Promise.all in App.js (I found a similar question before to asking) but I have not clear how I must change in the PokemonList component to print the list on screen.

Comment: _Which_ map is on undefined? And did you check what res.data actually is?

Comment: Consider using TypeScript to help find bugs like these at compile time.

Comment: i have solved! it was only a typo

Answer (score 2):

There is a typo. You have to change from `result` to `results`.

Comment: it's incredible how sometimes the errors are so simple!

Comment: Please don't answer questions where the solution is "Fix the typo". This type of question has no long term value since other people with the same problem are not going to find this by searching. "Typo" is one of the standard Close Vote reasons. Answering this type of question can block the OP from deleting it to remove bloat from StackOverflow. You can delete this answer to remove the possibility of blocking such clean up.